# Get console path in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm working on a console application for node.js and I need a little help. If you install my console app using 'npm', you'll be able to call it by typing 'program' but if my console is in the location `C:/Users/JhonDoe/Documents` how do I get that location in nodejs. I know how to get the script location (eg. `C:/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/program/bin`) but how to I get the location in the console.
To clarify my aim; I need to get a file inside the folder their currently in so I need to know the folder their calling my application from.
Thank You,
@_C1D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`process.cwd()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) gives the current working directory of the process.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I'll make sure to credit you in my project :D